# Deploying Expression Encoder SDK Without Installing

Tags: asp.net, deployment, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I am trying to prove a concept while using the Microsoft Expression Encoder 3 SDK.  I am trying to deploy the SDK to my hosted web server to understand more about whether or not that will work and what else needs to be installed.

I cannot get anything to work on the server.  Here are the 4 Dlls that I understand that I need that I am deploying in my bin folder:

- Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.dll
- Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Types.dll
- Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities.dll
- WindowsBase.dll

Note: I have not "installed" Expression Encoder on the Web Server, which is using Windows Server 2008.  I am just trying to drop the dlls out there.

As soon as I copy the file Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities.dll to the server bin directory, I get the error "The specified module could not be found."

Does anyone know how to deploy the Expression Encoder SDK without installing it on the server?  If that is not possible, it seems like a pretty huge "feature" to be missing from an SDK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official answer appears to be that the Expression Encoder SDK for version 3 cannot be deployed without installing the entire application.

See [this post](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/encoder/thread/9a1624c8-94bd-4b25-a1b7-e9e2e383ea1f#af401293-c187-494c-bbd8-7fb9d1d271ad) from the official Expression Encoder forum.

How disappointing.  I guess I will have to use another package.